# Dividing columns in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataset and I want to divide the "Dose" and "Count" columns by 100. I want my new dataset to include the "Visit" column as well.

However, using the code below, my new dataset does not have the "Visit" column.
What if I want to divide only the "Dose" column by 100?
I uploaded my dataset into R and called it data.

```
data_new=data[,2:ncol(data)]/100
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're not preserving the untouched columns in your new data frame is because you're only assigning the selected columns on which you've applied the vectorized division operation back to what you expect (at least based on how you're naming it) is a data frame.

```r
data$dose <- data$dose / 100
```

Comment: Ah, got you. I was making it complicated than it needed to be.  Thank you!

Comment: All good lol. One more thing—not that it'll *actually* make a difference in how your code runs, but it's good form to use `<-` to assign values instead of `=`, which should be reserved for function parameters.